# Distribution of deviations from order statistics

Tags: distributions, order-statistics

Consider a continuous r.v. $x$ with CDF $F(\cdot)$. Let $\{x_i,\,i=1,\ldots,n\}$ be a sample of $n$ IID draws, and let $\{x_{(i)},\,i=1,\ldots,n\}$ denote the order statistics; i.e., $x_{(1)}$ is the minimum, $x_{(n)}$ the maximum, etc. My question is: what is the distribution of the deviations from the $j$-th order statistic, i.e., $\{y_{ij} = x_i - x_{(j)},\,i=1,\ldots,n\}$? I think that since we know for sure that one of the $y_{ij}$ is zero, this distribution should be defined only for nonzero values. But aside from this, I wonder what kind of general results (i.e., for any $F(\cdot)$, $n$ and $j$) can be derived for this problem.